# How to change the variable of a method in Runnable?

Tags: android, runnable

What I want to do  is to change my run() method, such that it can receive different variables. I want to change player1life to something else, so that I can use **customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);** on a different one, such as player2life. 
What the code does, is, when a button is being pressed, a variable changes its value.

NOTE: I am an all most completely newbie in android development.

```
final android.os.Handler  customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    final Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {   if(pressed) {
            player1life--;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(player1life));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
        }
    };


    leftButton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    pressed = true;
                    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                    leftButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrownewred);
                    winFunction();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    pressed = false;
                    leftButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrownew); break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I smell an XY problem...

Why not create a different `Runnable` for handling `player2life`? In the on click handler, just do an if statement to check which players' life should you decrease!

```
if ... {
    customHandler.postDelayed(runnableThatHandlesPlayer1Life, 0);
} else {
    customHandler.postDelayed(runnableThatHandlesPlayer2Life, 0);
}
```

And the runnables can be declared this way:

```
final Runnable runnableThatHandlesPlayer1Life = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {   if(pressed) {
        player1life--;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(player1life));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
    }
};

final Runnable runnableThatHandlesPlayer2Life = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {   if(pressed) {
        player2life--;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(player2life));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
    }
};
```

But your code is kind of suspicious. From my understanding of your code, player1's life will decrease at a rate of 10/second when a button is pressed. It's strange.

It seems like that you're trying to create a timer thingy. Try this `Timer` class that I wrote. It should make things a bit easier:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is problem just getting past the need for `final` variables in the anonymous inner class?  If so, you can use the "trick" of using a final array of length 1, and then updating the element of the array.

Here is a simple example:

```
public interface Incrementer {

    void increment();

}

public class Foo {

    private int bar = 0;

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.bar++;
        System.out.println("value is now: " + bar); 
    }


}

 public class Closure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("hello");
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo();

        final Foo[] theFoo = {foo1};

        Incrementer incrementer = new Incrementer() {

            public void increment() {
                theFoo[0].increment();

            }

        };

        incrementer.increment();
        incrementer.increment();
        incrementer.increment();
        theFoo[0] = foo2;
        incrementer.increment();
        incrementer.increment();
        System.out.println("foo1 = " + foo1.getBar());
        System.out.println("foo2 = " + foo2.getBar());

    }

}
```